# Conditional yield (generator) in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, yield

I have multiple data sources pushing data to a common storage. Each data source is essentially just a pandas dataframe `itertuples()` iterator stored in the _all_data dictionary:

```
for ticker, df in dataframe.groupby('ticker'):
    self._all_data[ticker] = df.itertuples()
```

Then I have a method for yielding the next row of data. The goal is to only yield a row if it is meeting some requirements. In this case it must be a specific DateTime:

```
def _get_next_bar(self, ticker: str, datetime: pd.datetime):
    for bar in self._all_data[ticker]:
        if getattr(bar, 'time') == datetime:
            yield bar
```

The reason for this requirement is that each data source can have a different number of observations at different specific times, so I only want to yield a bar if the data storage has an observation at the current DateTime. I do this like this:

```
def update_bars(self):
    date = next(self._get_next_datetime())
    for ticker in self.ticker_list:
        try:
            next_bar = next(self._get_next_bar(ticker, date))
        except StopIteration:
            self.continue_backtest = False
        else:
            if next_bar is not None:
                self.historic_data[ticker].append(next_bar)
                self.events.put(MarketEvent(ticker))
```

where `_get_next_datetime()` is just defined as:

```
def _get_next_datetime(self):
    for datetime in self.all_datetimes:
        yield datetime
```

However, the problem is that whenever the bar is not meeting the requirement, the `StopIteration` exception is raised. This is a problem as this was supposed to be the signal to stop my program. If I remove the datetime requirement (if `getattr(bar, 'time') == datetime`) my program runs fine and raises the StopIteration error when the iterator is empty. However, if I keep the requirement, the error is raised at the first datetime without an observation.

How can I implement this in another way? Can I maybe create my own generator with custom exceptions using the `pd.itertuples()`?

Comment: How do you call `_get_next_bar`? Maybe `self._all_data[ticker]` doesn't contain what you think it does, because the code looks *OK*.

Comment: Thanks, @CristiFati. I have updated my question.

Comment: `_get_next_bar` should only raise `StopIteration` if _no_ `bar` meets the condition (or if the iterator itself is empty), not if the first `bar` does not meet it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't @tobias_k. If I remove the datetime requirement (if `getattr(bar, 'time') == datetime`) my program runs fine and raises the StopIteration error when the iterator is empty. However, if I keep the requirement, the error is raised at the first datetime without an observation.

Comment: @mfvas Then that means that no `bar` meets the condition. Are you sure that your data is correct, that `date` is as expected (and not, e.g. None, or having a different type), and that the key is really called `'time'` etc.?

Comment: I think you need to specify exactly when you want to set `self.continue_backtest = False` because that seems to be the crux of the question.